# Performing authorized (through facebook) REST requests to my node.js server on a PhoneGap app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, node.js, cordova

Since this issue is about three technologies I'd like to quickly introduce each of them:

- node.js: javascript on the server side (consider it my webserver)
- PhoneGap: framework that allows me to write Android applications in HTML/Javascript/CSS.
- facebook authentication: using [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) to let my users login with their facebook account

**The objective**: I need my PhoneGap application to communicate with my server using a REST based protocol. Many of these requests may only be made when the user has logged in to my server, using their Facebook account. Thus, the user needs to login and then go to the logged in state of the PhoneGap application.

**The issue**: When I setup everyauth for facebook I basically have an URL, like domain.com/auth/facebook which will redirect to Facebook's login "popup". When the user then accepts the login, the server will know, and so far everything is good. The problem is that

1. the user now has to be redirected to some external URL, while he should simply get back to the PhoneGap application (in a logged-in state)
2. The PhoneGap app does not retrieve the authentication token, or whether authentication was successful or not, because the login process is done in the external URL domain.com/auth/facebook while the PhoneGap application's HTML is stored on and run from the phone itself

**Cause of the issue**: the reason this issue appears while it does not for a normal web application, is that the PhoneGap application's HTML files are stored and run from the phone itself while authentication goes through domain.com/auth/facebook, which is considered to be a different domain.

**Suggested approach #1**: a PhoneGap user has recommended me to use this [Android-Facebook plugin for PhoneGap](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect). The issue here is that the server does not act as an authentication middle-man. Thus, the user would have to inform the server of their authentication token instead of the normal approach where the server informs the user of a successful authentication procedure and the corresponding tokens. This seems like a severe vulnerability.

How should I tackle this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [ChildBrowser plug-in](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser), a PhoneGap app can monitor location changes from the authentication site.

We used this approach to integrate a PhoneGap app with a [node.js openid module](https://github.com/havard/node-openid)

Comment: Very interesting. I take it this is the only available approach? Should the redirection URL then contain a query string (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) with all authentication info? I assume your code is not open source? Finally, do you send the retrieved auth token along with every request to the server?

Comment: I don't send the authentication info back to the client.  I use https://github.com/Marak/session.js to associate an authenticated session with a particular client session. Then subsequent client requests validate if they came from the same session that did the authentication. I'm sure there are plenty of other approaches, but this one does what I need. The PhoneGap app will be open sourced in the next few weeks. We haven't decided yet about the server

Comment: could you elaborate on the session mechanics, please? Since the PhoneGap application is run from a different place than where you have authenticated, it will not have the session cookies set, correct? Do you pass session IDs to the PhoneGap application from the callback URL in the ChildBrowser? Thanks.

Comment: With var session = require('sesh').magicSession(); request.session.id will uniquely identify the particular client session.  See the "Creating a super simple login / logout feature" section at  github.com/Marak/session.js. The PhoneGap app doesn't need to know about the session, but the server will know who it is.

Comment: We may be running agains one of the differences between OpenId and OAuth. With OpenId, it's enough to know that authentication happened, but does OAuth need the client to know the authentication tokens, so it can do more operations beyond validating the account is valid

Comment: I realize what a session identifier is. The issue is that the client has to send this session id, or cookie id, to the server when it makes a new request. Otherwise, the client cannot be identified by the server. I'm afraid you have not answered this question.

Comment: request.session.id DOES uniquely identify the client to the server. However, it seems like you also need the client to know about the server's authentication info. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Paul Beusterien, sure it does. I wish we could speak in real life, as whatever I type does not seem to get the point across. Maybe I can explain what the real issue is in a chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4123/discussion-between-tom-and-paul-beusterien)

Comment: did you get to ask that college of yours after our chat? Thanks.

Comment: I did, but she had nothing to add. We are dependent upon the ChildBrowser having the same session.

Comment: Did you confirm this or should I test it?

Comment: Yes. Confirmed that the server sees the ChildBrowser and app with the same session id

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented one solution for Twitter using [jsOauth](https://github.com/bytespider/jsOAuth) and ChildBrowser (tut./src [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt5p1)) for a PhoneGap / Android app. I know this doesn't include custom registration with a nodejs server; it allows access to Twitter REST only. AFAIK this is the only way to do it currently, that is, have the child browser check each new location to see if it's your app's return-to url, then intervene (close browser window) and go to your own app.

With jsOauth library, the auth token key/secret are stored for you and sent with every request.

Re: security - No expertise here, but discussions conclude this kind of data on one's personal phone are no more at risk than everything else on the phone.

Tut. using PhoneGap / Android Facebook plugin in next on my list. Thanks for link to everyauth!

Comment: Interesting. If you're going for the tutorial, may I suggest using everyauth so it will be applicable for multiple services? Also, I'd include registering with the server since most applications need more than just the API of a service like twitter. Anyway, I am trying to implement this now. The issue is that the page being redirected to does not have any parameters in the URL. What parameters should be sent? Some kind of auth token?

Comment: I've now added that issue to everyauth: https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth/issues/93

Comment: Yes, the breadth of everyauth makes it very interesting. My limited understanding is that implementation client-side for oauth+whomever may need to be specific to that whomever. Twitter's callback_url + jsOauth made that solution very easy (w/ChildBrowser).

Comment: And.. another useful library is http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/ which I'm using for a different phonegap app. Using the node.js open module mentioned by Paul, custom query strings can be tacked onto a return url (see /verify path: build and write Location+query string instead of his "Success :)" to send something back to the client, like username or loginOk etc). Oh yeah, if you happen to use jquery ajax, then http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm is worth its weight..

Comment: I'm afraid you're not fully aware of my issue. I need future REST requests made from PhoneGap to be recognized as the logged in user by my server. Thus, when user is logged in, the session identifier needs to be passed to the PhoneGap application in one way or another. I have repeated this numerous times in this thread now but it seems like we keep talking about different things. ;)